# Differential equation for a circle at the origin with an arbitrary radius C

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms

I my mathematical journey I've stumbled upon an a way to represent any circle of a radius $R$ given that the original equation is of the form: $$y=\pm \sqrt{R^2 - x^2},$$
in terms of a differential equation, we get: $$y\frac{dy}{dx} + x = 0$$

Now i was thinking on deriving a form made by myself, and was wondering how to best tackle the problem...I was thinking along the lines of an exact differential equation of the first order using the properties of the total differential. Considering that a circle can be thought of the level cuve of a cylindrical surface that can be expressed as: $$f(x,y) = C$$

Am I on the right path though? Please, no one show how to explicitly do it...a few tips should suffice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well you can start with $$x^2 + y^2 = R^2$$ and differentiate implicitly, to get $$2x+2yy'=0$$

Solve for $y'$ to get your differential equation.

Comment: +1 more simple with implicit differentiation

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani Right just now i came up with df = 2x dx + 2y dy = 0, but I am not quite sure about this...

Comment: wait, i suspect this to be wrong...

Comment: @SSBASE You can divide by $2$ or solve for $\frac {dy}{dx}$

Comment: @MommadRiazi-Kermani If I divide by 2, then wouldn't I get df/2?

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani  mathjax doesn't work on comments...I don't know why...

Comment: @S forget about df.  You divide by 2 and get xdx+ydy =0 which is your equation.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani  I just noticed that your implicit differentiation method and my total derivative method yield the same  dy/dx + x/y = 0...I love mathematics!

Comment: @SSBASE That is great. Thanks for your attention.